# Can't get the output from my aiohttp request.get

Tags: python, api, python-asyncio, databricks

I am trying to get a lot of data from an api. The URL is always the same, but the parameters change (I have to get the data for about 20 consecutive dates). I initially did it sequentially and it was way too long so I decided to give asyncio / aiohttp a go.
I work with databricks and ultimately the data will be saved in a datalake.
I have two functions:

```
async def executeCallAllDates(endPoint, parameters):
  
  forDateString = parameters['updatedBefore'][:parameters['updatedBefore'].find('T')]
  forDate = datetime.strptime(forDateString, '%Y-%m-%d')

  rangeStart = forDate - timedelta(days=14)
  rangeEnd = forDate + timedelta(days=5)

  authHeader = {'authorization':'Bearer ' + bytecurveToken}
  finalEndPoint = "https://api.anapiprovider.com/" + endPoint
  tasks = []
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    for dt in daterange(rangeStart, rangeEnd):
      parameters['startDate'] = datetime.strftime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
      tasks.append(session.get(finalEndPoint, headers=authHeader, params=parameters))

    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print(type(responses))
  return responses
```

My second function will execute the first one:

```
def executeCallAsync(endPoint, parameters, schema):

  responses = asyncio.run(executeCallAllDates(endPoint, parameters))
  results = []
  for response in responses:
    responseJson = response.json()
    print( f"The current response is: {responseJson}")
    if not(response):
      results.append(responseJson)
    if len(results) > 0:
      return results
    else: 
      print(f"There was no data updated on {parameters['updatedBefore']}")
      None

  if result:
    df = spark.createDataFrame(result, schema)
    return df
  else:
    return None
```

when I run this, there are no error messages due to the API call itself. It looks like it is running, waiting a few seconds (expected) and the resumes. When I loop through the list of results, I look at the response.status (200, OK) and I was expecting to have some json data in responseJson but instead, I have this:
`The current response is: <coroutine object ClientResponse.json at 0x7fa0b5bb8740>`
What am I doing wrong? If in `response.status()` I have and actual status, I should have an actual json in `response.json()`.
I tried different things, using asyncio.wait(), instead of asyncio.gather()

Comment: [`ClientResponse.json`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.json) is a **coroutine**, my friend. You may want to `await` it. ;-) [`ClientResponse.status`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.status) is just an attribute. [RTFM](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#json-response-content)

Comment: I am just beginning with async programing so there are a few things I don't get (maybe a lot!).

My understanding of `responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` was that it would run all my tasks and return the result in a tuple, in my case, `result`. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=gather#asyncio.gather

--> the result is an aggregate list of returned values.
Is result not what I think it is? the result of my API call?
Then how do I await all my coroutines? Should I loop through my tuple of coroutines?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing this output in your console is that [`ClientResponse.json`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.json) is a [**coroutine** function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine-function), which means that when you do `response_json = response.json()`, you now have a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) assigned to `response_json`. To get its output, you have to *schedule* it for execution, which is typically done via the `await` keyword.

You need to understand that the [`ClientSession.get`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession.get) function (or more accurately the request context manager it returns) does not automatically download the response body. It establishes the connection and saves headers, status code and some other things in a `ClientResponse` object. The response body can then be loaded with various methods of that object (like `text` or `json`). But those are all `async` methods and thus need to be scheduled and `await`ed at some point.

So your use of tasks and [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) to asynchronously perform the `GET` requests is not *wrong* per se. It will ensure the requests are made, it is just not going to give you the response bodies. If you want to get those right away as well, you need to refactor your code a bit. And keep the `.json()` call inside an `async` function.

Here is a reasonable pattern:

```py
from asyncio import create_task, gather
from collections.abc import Mapping
from typing import Any

from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def get_data(
    url: str,
    headers: Mapping[str, str],
    params: Mapping[str, str],
    session: ClientSession,
) -> Any:
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers, params=params) as response:
        return await response.json()


async def get_all(url: str, params: Mapping[str, str]) -> list[Any]:
    tasks = []
    ...
    headers = {}
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for _ in range(5):
            tasks.append(create_task(get_data(url, headers, params, session)))
        return await gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: Thank you, I implemented a solution that's 90% what you wrote. And it does work... sometime.
The way this calls are made is as follow:
`jDataList = asyncio.run(get_All(url, params=parameters))`
If I understand correctly, `get_all()` will schedule my coroutines for execution and `asyncio.run()` will execute everything, wait until each coroutine is executed and then assign a list of results to my jDataList.
My problem is that sometime, the data is in my list, sometimes it is not. It is as if there was a time out. I did not see any obvious pattern underlying with and without data.